# Why does force Unwrapping give me an EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) Error?

Tags: swift, swift3

My application is crashing on the declaration of my for loop `for participant in event.attendees!`. I'm relatively new to swift and understood that if I check that the attendees array is not nil then I'm free to force unwrap it. What have I misunderstood here?

```
    private static func parseParticipants(event: EKEvent) -> [Attendee] {
    var participants = [Attendee]()

    if(event.attendees != nil && event.attendees?.count != 0) {
        for participant in event.attendees! {
            let participantName = parseEKParticipantName(participant)

            let isRequiredParticipant = participant.participantRole == EKParticipantRole.Required
            let hasAccepted = participant.participantStatus == EKParticipantStatus.Accepted
            let attendee = Attendee(name: participantName, email: participant.URL.resourceSpecifier!.lowercaseString, required: isRequiredParticipant, hasAccepted: hasAccepted)
            participants.append(attendee)
        }
    }
    return participants
}
```

Comment: I have tried this simple example in playground and it works fine. 
http://paste.ofcode.org/vc6q8kYyYq5Sk5HjqNSrAf

Can you provide more details?

Comment: @ArG It does for me as well, but some of my users are sending crash reports that direct to this line of code. I've been unable to duplicate the error so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was not about force unwrapping but was due to the `EKParticipant.url` property returning nil when it contained a String contained a `"` character.

`let attendee = Attendee(name: participantName, email: participant.URL.resourceSpecifier!.lowercaseString, required: isRequiredParticipant, hasAccepted: hasAccepted)`

We used this to access the participants email but any read or write operation to the `url` caused a crash so we took the `EKParticipant.description` property and parsed the email using a regular expression.

`let participantEmail = participant.description.parse(pattern: emailRegex).first ?? ""`

Answer (score 0):

How about using optional binding?

```
if let attendees = event.attendees && attendees.count > 0 {

}
```

Comment: I gave this a go but didn't work unfortunately.
It's precisely what apple's SIGTRAP description describes as the main cause so I'm surprised it didn't.